# What does the term VARIANT mean in a method definition?

Tags: c#

I'm working on in ABBYY Flexicapture that allows some of the scripts to be written in C#.NET, Ive never use C#.NET but it's close enough to Java that I'm getting by.  I have a `method` declaration that shows the following:

```
Document:
    Property (name: string) : VARIANT
        Description: Retrieves the value of a specified property by its name. The returned value can be in the form of a string, a number or time.
        Properties names and returned values: 
            Exported - when the document was exported 
            ExportedBy - who exported the document 
            Created - when the document was created 
            CreatedBy - who created the document
```

So I'm trying to get the "Exported By" value but when I try any of the the following lines I get errors:

```
string = Document.Property("CreatedBy"); // Returns Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) (line 95, pos 21)
string = Document.Property(CreatedBy);  // Returns Error: Error: The name 'CreatedBy' does not exist in the current context (line 95, pos 39)
string = Document.Property("CreatedBy").Text; //Error: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Text' (line 95, pos 52
```

I've never seen the `VARIANT` used before, can someone explain this to me.  Is there an obvious syntax error Im missing?

Comment: object s = Document.Property("CreatedBy");?

Comment: string = Document.Property("CreatedBy"); // Returns Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. This error message tells you that Document.Property("CreatedBy") is an object.

Comment: @Vlad - Thanks, that was it.  Then I converted it `.ToString()` and everything worked well.

Comment: @sgmoore - I agree, I was confused becasue the method said it would return one of the three datatypes but didnt list object.  I returned it as an object and converted it to a string and it worked.

Comment: @Vlad - Put your answer below and Ill mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variant is actually "union" of different types. A good way to express this is just

```
object o = Document.Property("CreatedBy");
```

You can now check the exact type of `o`:

```
if (o is string)
{
    string s = (string)o;
    // work with string s
}
else if (o is int)
{
    int i = (int)o;
    // work with int i
}
// etc. for all possible actual types
```

Alternately, you can convert the object to string representation (`o.ToString()`) and work with it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with ABBYY Flexicapture but I've done some COM back in the day and that made heavy use of VARIANT. It's basically a value type that can be either a string, number or date.

This seems to line up with the Description given in the declaration you've quoted:

> The returned value can be in the form of a string, a number or time.

A VARIANT is similar to a variable in weakly typed (scripting) languages like javascript.

For more details, check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_type).